# Monotonic Polynomials

Tags: probability-distributions

I need to fit a cumulative distribution that is monotonically decreasing. I have in mind to use a polynomial of the lowest order that will give a fit that is looks good to the eye. Can someone suggest a polynomial functional form that is monotonically decreasing?

Comment: over what domain?

Comment: Cumulative distribution functions tend to be increasing.

Comment: Either use a polynomial in e.g. $e^{-z}$ or a rational function. Plain polynomials don't have asymptotes (and a cumulative distribution does $\rightarrow 1$ as $z \rightarrow \infty$). I.e., get the _overall_ form right and then adjust parameters.

Answer (score 1):

While polynomials can be  decreasing or increasing (e.g., $f(x)=-x$ or $f(x)=x^3$), they cannot have a finite limit as $x\to\infty$ (except by being a constant function). Both suggestions by vonbrand are very good: use a polynomial of $e^{-x}$ or a rational function of $x$. Lacking further information, I would go with the polynomial of $e^{-x}$ (or a similar decaying function), because in this case we get a *linear* system of equations for coefficients, when fitting the curve using least squares method.